# Why doesn't visual studio always remember to break on a common language run time exception?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In VS2013, using Control Alt E, I check "Break when a common language runtime exception is thrown."  However a few days later I often find this setting has been lost.
Why would that happen?

Comment: The setting value is stored in the hidden .suo file for a solution.  So simply switching from one solution to another is enough to "lose" the setting.  Or any other scenario you can think of where that .suo file is not used or overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen things like that happen is when I have multiple copies of Visual Studio open at once.  It seems that some settings are only saved when VS is closed, but are not picked up by other running instances.  Depending on the order you exit out of then Visual Studio instances some settings can get overwritten or lost.

Comment: great, i will wait a few days to try and be sure this is it.